# Purpose of md5 in multipart/mixed e-mail form data

Tags: php, email, md5, multipartform-data, multipart

I would like to know the purpose of the `md5("sanwebe")` checksum in the following PHP snippet which I found [here](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=54001) and [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2014/04/ajax-contact-form-attachment-jquery-php).
What does the "sanwebe" parameter do?

```
if($file_attached) //continue if we have the file
{
  $boundary = md5("sanwebe"); 
  //header
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; 
  $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$email."" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 

  //plain text 
  $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
  $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
  $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
  $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body)); 

  //attachment
  $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
  $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
  $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
  $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
  $body .= $encoded_content; 
}else{
  //proceed with PHP email.
  $headers = "From:".$from_email."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $body = $message_body;
}
```

Comment: Boundary is mandatory to separate html version from plain text version, it's a delimiter =)

Comment: multipart emails are separated by a 'boundary', a string that must not appear in the content of the email. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `md5("sanwebe")` is being used as the boundary for different sections of content in the email.

Why "sanwebe"? No reason at all. The snippet you have there was probably posted on sanwebe.com (a quick google brings up a couple), or has been derived from a snippet that was there originally. There is nothing special at all about "sanwebe", you could just as well use `md5("stackoverflow")`.

Comment: The only requirement is that the boundary string is not duplicated in the content. A UUID or sufficiently long random string is usually used for this purpose.

Comment: Yep. MD5 hashes are ideal for this.

Comment: Using MD5 for anything feels dirty. SHA256 is probably a better bet. Generally these don't have to be cryptographically secure, but you want to minimize the possibility of email content conflicting with the boundaries.

Comment: There really is no reason to shy away from MD5 considering the context here. The _reality_ is that any collisions are going to be manufactured. Of course, there's also no reason to not use SHA256. It is somewhat slower, but that's never going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: When running a handful of times, as is the case when generating an email, it is not even measurably slower. Speed is absolutely not an issue. SHA256 produces larger values and is far more collision resistant, so there's really no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The different parts in a multipart MIME message have to have a kind of marker so that the receipient knows where to split the parts again.
This is done by defining an arbitrary token using the boundary parameter of the Content-Type mail header. There are not much requirements to this token but one is: I may not be present anywhere else in the mail.

The use of the md5 function in the code snipped you showed just uses the md5 function to generate some token that is probably not present elsewhere in the message. You could use any other parameter to the md5 aswell or you could just define the $boundary variable to contain any other random string.